# Can anyone suggest any open source software like visio that can create data driven and control?

Tags: visio

I need to know what i can use to create data driven infographics without having to install visio i cant to control those graphic based on my data and embed the diagram in excel or a dashboard and ensure the diagram always refreshes with the excel data.

Comment: Recommendation requests are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: where can i get recommendations from?

Comment: That is another recommendation request.

Comment: Dont know why youre being so difficult but thanks to whoever answered me

Comment: Dura lex, sed lex.

Answer (score -1):

MongoDB

free database software

MongoDB was founded in 2007 and is known as the “database for giant ideas.” Developed by the people behind DoubleClick, ShopWiki, and Gilt Groupe, MongoDB is also backed by popular investors such as Fidelity Investments, The Goldman Sachs Group, Inc., and Intel Capital. Since its inception, MongoDB has been downloaded 20 million times and is supported by more than 1,000 partners. These partners are dedicated to this free and open source solution’s belief that coding and databases should be simple and natural.

Pros

Document validation
Encrypted storage engine
Common use cases:
Mobile apps
Product catalogs
Content management
Real-time apps with in-memory storage engine (beta)
Reduces time between primary failure and recovery
Cons

Doesn’t fit applications needing complex transactions
Not a drop-in replacement for legacy applications
Young solution: software changes and evolves quickly